# The "sin-cos-maximum" function

Tags: functions

Is there some specific notation for the function

$f(x):=\max\{\cos(x),\sin(x)\}$,

or maybe some equivalent compact expression?

Improvement: Actually, maybe a compact equivalent expression for its squared version

$g(x):=\max\{\cos^2(x),\sin^2(x)\}$,

is easier.

Comment: look at what a "robot" can do http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+max%7Bcos+x%2C+sin+x%7D

Comment: A useful answer to "equivalent expression" depends largely on the context you intend to use such an expression for.

Answer (score 1):

A way is:
$$f(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \cos{x}, & \left[2\pi k-\frac{3\pi}{4},2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]\\\\
    \sin{x}, & \left[2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{4},2\pi k+\frac{5\pi}{4}\right]
  \end{array}
\right.,\quad \text{with}\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Well, the intervals are compact.

Comment: @Arkamis In the end points, $\sin{x}=\cos{x}$.

Comment: I know. I was remarking that the OP wanted a compact expression. This is... decidedly less so ;)